# Add JavaScript-Library "Fitty" to WordPress

Tags: javascript, library

as I am trying to figure this one out since hours, I've come to the conclusion, I should have a try, asking you guys.

I want to integrate the JavaScript Library "Fitty" (https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty?fbclid=IwAR0m6k5jCxiTar6qNlPncS0X7phdD4YEyKePUSEqMPO4dg2LrV1QRrHJupc) in my WordPress installation.

I followed several tutorials but wasn't able to figure out, how to integrate exactly that library.

Anybody out there, who could help me out with that one, please?

Thanks in advance,

Dorian.

Comment: I would suggest making a child theme and then enqueue the script in the functions.php file of your child theme - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Hey @RiddleMeThis, 

I've already added the library to the /scripts-folder in my child theme.
Is enqueueing the script in the functions.php of my child theme really everything I need to do, to get it running?

Comment: According to their docs all you need is dist/fitty.min.js, just enqueue that then use fitty('#my-element'); to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

1- First you have to make a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) of your current theme.
2- Then, in your child theme create a `functions.php` file
3- Create a `js` folder and put `fitty.min.js` inside it and create a `child.js` file also inside this `js` folder
4- In **functions.php** of your child theme add the following :

```
<?php // Opening PHP tag - nothing should be before this, not even whitespace
function child_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'fitty', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/fitty.min.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/fitty.min.js' ) ), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'child', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/child.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/child.js' ) ), true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_scripts' );
```

5- In **child.js** add the following :

```
(function ($) {

    fitty('#my-element'); // Here fitty is targeting the element with an id='my-element' 

})(jQuery);
```

Hope this will help you :)